# Find the importance of each column to the model

Tags: machine-learning, ml.net

I have a ML.net project and as of right now everything has gone great. I have a motor that collects a power reading 256 times around each rotation and I push that into a model. Right now it determines the state of the motor nearly perfectly. The motor itself only has room for 38 values on it at a time so I have been spending several rotations to collect the full 256 samples for my training data.

I would like to cut the sample size down to 38 so every rotation I can determine its state. If I just evenly space the samples down to 38 my model degrades by a lot. I know I am not feeding the model the features it thinks are most important but just making a guess and randomly selecting data for the model.

Is there a way I can see the importance of each value in the array during the training process? I was thinking I could use IDataView for this and I found the below statement about it ([link](https://xadupre.github.io/machinelearningext/mlnetdocs/idataviewdesignprinciples.html#vector-types)).

> Standard ML schema: The IDataView system does not define, nor prescribe, standard ML schema representation. For example, it does not dictate representation of nor distinction between different semantic interpretations of columns, such as label, feature, score, weight, etc. However, the column metadata support, together with conventions, may be used to represent such interpretations.

Does this mean I can print out such things as weight for each column and how would I do that?

I have actually only been working with ML.net for a couple weeks now so I apologize if the question is naive, I assure you I have googled this as many ways as I can think to. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Thank you for the answer I was going down a completely useless path. I have been trying to get it to work following the example you linked to. I have 260 columns with numbers and one column with the conditions as one of five text strings. This is the condition I am trying to predict.

The first time I tried it threw an error "expecting single but got string". No problem I used .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey("Label", "Label")) to convert to key values and it threw the error expected Single, got Key UInt32. any ideas on how to push that into this function?

At any rate thank you for the reply but I guess my upvotes don't count yet sorry. hopefully I can upvote it later or someone else here can upvote it. Below is the code example.

```
  //Create MLContext
  MLContext mlContext = new MLContext();

  //Load Data
  IDataView data = mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile<ModelInput>(TRAIN_DATA_FILEPATH, separatorChar: ',', hasHeader: true);

  // 1. Get the column name of input features.
  string[] featureColumnNames =
      data.Schema
          .Select(column => column.Name)
          .Where(columnName => columnName != "Label").ToArray();

  // 2. Define estimator with data pre-processing steps
  IEstimator<ITransformer> dataPrepEstimator =
      mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", featureColumnNames)
          .Append(mlContext.Transforms.NormalizeMinMax("Features"))
          .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey("Label", "Label"));

  // 3. Create transformer using the data pre-processing estimator
  ITransformer dataPrepTransformer = dataPrepEstimator.Fit(data);//error here

  // 4. Pre-process the training data
  IDataView preprocessedTrainData = dataPrepTransformer.Transform(data);

  // 5. Define Stochastic Dual Coordinate Ascent machine learning estimator
  var sdcaEstimator = mlContext.Regression.Trainers.Sdca();

  // 6. Train machine learning model
  var sdcaModel = sdcaEstimator.Fit(preprocessedTrainData);

  ImmutableArray<RegressionMetricsStatistics> permutationFeatureImportance =
      mlContext
          .Regression
          .PermutationFeatureImportance(sdcaModel, preprocessedTrainData, permutationCount: 3);


  // Order features by importance
  var featureImportanceMetrics =
      permutationFeatureImportance
          .Select((metric, index) => new { index, metric.RSquared })
          .OrderByDescending(myFeatures => Math.Abs(myFeatures.RSquared.Mean));

  Console.WriteLine("Feature\tPFI");

  foreach (var feature in featureImportanceMetrics)
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"{featureColumnNames[feature.index],-20}|\t{feature.RSquared.Mean:F6}");
  }
```

Comment: If you are trying to get the feature importance irrespective of the model you use, then try `forward/backward feature selection`.  [This link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html) would help

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is called [Permutation Feature Importance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/permutation-feature-importance). This will tell you which features are most important by changing each feature in isolation, and then measuring how much that change affected the model's performance metrics. You can use this to see which features are the most important to the model.

[Interpret model predictions using Permutation Feature Importance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/explain-machine-learning-model-permutation-feature-importance-ml-net) is the doc that describes how to use this API in ML.NET.

Comment: Thank you, After trying to follow the example in the link I was able to get it to work on the example data. When I tried to convert it to my data first it threw an error because one of my columns is text so I used MapValueToKey("Label", "Label")) to convert to numbers but then it threw "expected Single, got Key<UInt32>". I was curious if had an idea on that as well. I will edit my first post to show the code but I am marking this as answered. Thanks for the help!

Comment: `MapValueToKey` is used when you are doing classification (either binary or multi-class). However, you are using a regression learner above: `mlContext.Regression.Trainers.Sdca()`. Since your `Label` is a string, you are doing classification. You should pick `mlContext.BinaryClassification` or `mlContext.MulticlassClassification` to get a trainer.

Comment: Thank you Eric, I believe I am starting to understand. That would make a lot of sense because the example was trying to make a prediction on a house price. I was trying to piece what together with this but i kept doing it wrong thank you for showing me what was wrong about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an open-source set of packages, they are much more sophisticated than what is found in ML.NET. I have an example on my GitHub how-to use R with advanced explainer packages to explain ML.NET models.  You can get local instance as well as global model breakdown/details/diagnostics/feature interactions etc.

https://github.com/bartczernicki/BaseballHOFPredictionWithMlrAndDALEX